# How to test/verify Firebase Dynamic Link referrals in Prod for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase Dynamic Links to implement an app referral system. However, when clicking on the link for an iOS device, it takes me to the app store page for the app. In other words there is no way to test if the referral link will be  successfully passed on to the app after installation without having to deploy the app into the production app store first.

This isn't too much of an issue on Android as I can use the various testing tracks to test installations.

Does anyone with similar experiences know of any other options?

Answer (score 0):

It is harder. As long as the bundle ID is the same though you should be deploy the app on to the device directly (via XCode, Testflight or other) after visiting the app store, and launching the app should retrieve the deeplink.